# Symfony2 form collection: Index of the current object is shown

Tags: forms, symfony

I've got a problem with displaying collection in my form.

When displaying my entity collection I've got something like this :

```
0
Name: myInputName
Address: myInputAddress

1
Name: myInputName
Address: myInputAddress
```

My question is why Symfony2 display the **index**...

And this for all saved entities into my collection...

Here the code I use:

```
$builder            
        ->add('person', 'collection', array(   
            'label' => ' ',             
            'type' => new PersonType(),
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
    ;
```

In my twig file:

```
<div>
    {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}    
</div>
```

Help please

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can custom the rendering of your collection for don't display the index with, by example:

```
{% block _FORMNAME_person_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {{ form_widget(child.Name) }}
        {{ form_widget(child.Address) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thank you so much... The spaceless method remove the label without the widget?

Comment: "remove whitespace between HTML tags" (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html)
Its use is common in \vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. Rather, it just hides the index from being displayed. I wonder how you would change the index to say, another value of the entity?

Comment: I still wonder why symfony hasn't put more effort into theming of collections. It just seems like too much PITA as of now.

Answer (score 83):

Removing indexes (labels) for collection items:

```
$builder            
    ->add('person', 'collection', array(
        ...
        'options' => array('label' => false)
    ))
;
```

> Use key `entry_options` instead of `options` for Symfony 3 and 4

If you want to add custom labels per row you can produce the form yourself:

```
{{ form_start(edit_form) }}
    {% for person in form.persons %}
        {{ form_row(person, {'label': 'custom label per item' }) }}
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(edit_form) }}
```

**Note**: tested on Symfony 2.3 & 2.4

Comment: I was hoping to do it within the builder, but this solution will do. Thanks!

Comment: For symfony3 use `'entry_options'` instead of `'options'`

Comment: @sectus same for Symfony 4

Comment: Does someone know a more generic solution? Is there something like a predefined FormType in a Bundle where you can define a LabelField in the form builder directly?

Answer (score 7):

This one is some days ago but because I was facing same question for Symfony 3 the answer of sectus is the correct one.

Use the

```
'entry_options' => ['label'=>false],
```

option within your builder to hide he object item.

Best Regards

Comment: this works with Symfony 4 [see the Answer from Dovydas Bartkevičius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21061645/1273555)

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been closed for a while. And not sure if this has been solved elsewhere. This issue is actually pretty simple to fix and I am surprised there is no documentation about this anywhere. In the PersonType or any type that is used in a collections just modify the vars['name'] in the buildView to be what you want displayed as the label.

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    // Adjust the view based on data passed
    $this->vars['name'] = $form->getData();
    // Or...
    $this->vars['name'] = 'Some random string';
}
```

If you want it dynamic, you would use the object by form->getData(). Since, in my problem, I am using a form theme, overriding the twig is not really an option for me.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I don't know if this has changed in Symfony 2.7 but it seems to now be `$form->vars['name'] = 'Foo bar baz';`

Comment: In Symfony 3 it is `$view->vars['name']`

Answer (score 0):

Using @MrBandersnatch's solution below, I had to use `$view->vars['name']` instead of `$this->vars['name']` (Symfony 2.3).

(apologies for not adding this as a comment on @MrBandersnatch's answer, I've not got enough reputation yet).