# Symfony2: Form Collection, custom label

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I would like to know how can I set different labels for a collection of entities in a form

This is my controller

```
        $company = new Company();


    $cf_entry = new CustomFieldEntry();
    $cf_entry->setCustomFieldId(13);
    $company->getCustomFieldEntries()->add($cf_entry);

    $cf_entry2 = new CustomFieldEntry();
    $cf_entry2->setCustomFieldId(14);
    $company->getCustomFieldEntries()->add($cf_entry2);



    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($company)
      ->setAction($this->generateUrl('company_new'))
      ->add('customFieldEntries', 'collection',
        array('type' => new CustomFieldEntryType()))
      ->add('save', 'submit')
      ->getForm();
```

And my form type

```
class CustomFieldEntryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('value');
    }
```

In this case I want to have different labels for the field 'value'

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you seek is here: [Symfony2 form collection: Index of the current object is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910563/symfony2-form-collection-index-of-the-current-object-is-shown)

you have to personalize form.

Comment: When posting links, please summarize the information in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `label` name like:

```
class CustomFieldEntryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('value', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Your New Label Name',
        ));
    }
```

Also this doc [The label option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options) will be usefull for you

Comment: My only problem with that is that I'm going to have the same label for both elements (if I have multiple elements in the collection)

Comment: You can to use same label for both elements, it's normally

Answer (score 0):

Just posted an answer to this here (that thread was a little harder to find): [Symfony Forms - How to Change a CollectionTypes Items labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362635/symfony-forms-how-to-change-a-collectiontypes-items-labels/57200558#57200558)